# Matlab - using a built in function within a function

Tags: matlab, function, input

Hi as part of a simulation assignment with matlab I want to write an input function. I want it to ask the user for inputs and then return them as outputs. 
I am using the built in function input. As a test I tried the following:

```
function x = testing
x = input('what is the number?')
end
```

I got the following error: 
Attempt to execute SCRIPT input as a function
What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: Do you have a script called `input` in your current directory? Try `which input`.

Comment: @beaker yes this was the issue thanks so much!

Comment: Better to use a configuation file/struct. It is hard to automate simulations if `input` is used. Also it is error prone. Anyway, this is just a tip.